# report Segmentation fault when loop the struct

Tags: c, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct group {
    int no;
    int people_len;
    struct people *peoples;
    int weight;
};

struct people {
    char name[4];
    int weight;
};

int main() {
    int n,k;
    if (scanf("%d %d", &n, &k) < 2) return 0;

    struct group *g;
    char from[4], to[4];
    int f1 = -1, f2 = -1, time, g_len = 0, p_len = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if (scanf("%s %s %d", from, to, &time) < 3) return 0;
        g = realloc(g, (g_len+1) * sizeof(struct group));
        g[g_len].no = g_len;
        g[g_len].people_len = 2;
        g[g_len].peoples = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct people));
        strcpy(g[g_len].peoples[0].name, from);
        strcpy(g[g_len].peoples[1].name, to);
        g[g_len].weight = time;
        g_len++;
    }
}
```

When I receive the parameters, it will report an 'Segmentation fault' error, I know that the memory is not processed well, but I can't find the problem.

Ihe input is:

> 8 59
>   AAA BBB 10
>   BBB AAA 20
>   AAA CCC 40
>   DDD EEE 5
>   EEE DDD 70
>   FFF GGG 30
>   GGG HHH 20
>   HHH FFF 10

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks like to be in

```
g = realloc(g, (g_len+1) * sizeof(struct group));
```

where, the argument `g` in uninitialized and points to some invalid memory location.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5

> If `ptr` is a null pointer, the `realloc` function behaves like the `malloc` function for the
>   specified `size`. Otherwise, if `ptr` does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory
>   management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to the `free` or
>   `realloc` function, the behavior is undefined. [...]

Since, in your case `g` is an automatic local variable, it is unitialized and it contains indeterminate value. To make it proper, you need to initialize it to `NULL`, something like

```
struct group *g = NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
struct group *g = NULL;
```

you're passing an un-initialized pointer to `realloc()`, which is undefined behavior.

Also note that if there's always going to be 2 people, it's better to just do:

```
struct people peoples[2];
```

inside the structure, to cut down on heap allocations and make things simpler.

It's also customary/standard to not do the re-allocation one element at a time, but instead let it grow exponentially by doubling the size on each new allocation need, or at last by adding a larger number of elements. This is since heap allocations are expensive (they take time), it's good for performance to make fewer allocations if possible. Of course, this requires tracking the actual used/valid of the array separately from the allocated length.

Comment: thanks,Can run normally. peoples is dynamic, so i use a struct pointer.